# Can't download apps on my iPhone

Tags: iphone

So I have an iPhone 4s and it has the new updates, but the apps stopped working. When I clicked on the app it flashed on the screen but then went back to home screen. I deleted the apps and tried to download them again but when I click the download button it goes to the square in a circle for one or two seconds then goes back to the download logo. I don't want to reset my phone but I don't know what to do. Other than that, my phone is perfect and it's not slow and never freezes.

Comment: Are you on the latest iOS version?  There was a problem with these symptoms on 9.3.1.

Comment: I think this question requires a little clarification. What version of iOS are you running? When did you start noticing the problem? What app or apps specifically are having that problem? What are you referring to specifically by "it has the new updates"?

Comment: Anyways I remember on my iPhone 4S (iOS 7.1) I was having similar problems, not exactly but similar. What you might want to try is syncing your phone over iTunes, download that app to iTunes and have it install to your phone there.

Answer (score 1):

It's because iPhone 4 can't be updated to the latest iOS while most of apps require later iOS than the latest iOS iPhone 4 can be updated. You shouldn't have updated the apps before updating the iOS.

Comment: They are running an iPhone 4S, not an iPhone 4. It does support iOS 9, though it is slow and not a good phone to keep on using.